# JavaScript - Merge 2 object after filter

Tags: javascript

I have this `old_data` array of objects variable:

```
let old_data = [
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: "additional_image_mapped",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: "brand_mapped",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
];
```

Now, I am filtering this variable where **text** is not `do_not_import`

```
let filter_data = old_data.filter( ( item ) => {
    return item.text != 'do_not_import';
});
```

Now, I got this result:

```
[ 
    { 
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: 'additional_image_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true 
    },
    { 
        value: 'brand',
        text: 'brand_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true 
    } 
]
```

Okay. now I have `new_data` varilable:

```
let newData = [
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'new',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
];
```

Now, I want to merged `new_data` and `filter_data` variable that should return all the data from the `filter_data` and all the data from `new_data` but from the `new_data` it should return those data which key `value` is not same in `filter_data` variable.

**Thats mean the output I want is :**

```
[ 
    { 
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: 'additional_image_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true
    },
    { 
        value: 'brand',
        text: 'brand_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true 
    },
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'new',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    }
]
```

Comment: Do you want to merge two arrays, not objects?

Comment: there is no only array, I have array of objects.

Comment: I think no, could you please give me a solution with my given data?

Comment: what goes wrong? please add your code.

Comment: I have no idea how to get my desire output :(

Comment: create a Set containing the values of the filter_data. then filter the new array which doesn't have in the above set. combine the two arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job-

```js
let old_data = [
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: "additional_image_mapped",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: "brand_mapped",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
];
let filter_data = old_data.filter( ( item ) => {
    return item.text != 'do_not_import';
});
let newData = [
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
    {
        value: 'new',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates : true, 
        removes : true,        
    },
];

var values = new Set(filter_data.map(v => v.value));

var merged = [...filter_data, ...newData.filter(v => !values.has(v.value))];

console.log(merged)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

const combinedData = newData.reduce((acc, element) => acc.some(e => e.value === element.value) ? acc : [...acc, element], filteredData);

Answer (score 0):

```js
const filterData = [
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: 'additional_image_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: 'brand_mapped',
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true
    }
];

const newData = [
    {
        value: 'item',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true,
    },
    {
        value: 'additional_image',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true,
    },
    {
        value: 'brand',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true,
    },
    {
        value: 'new',
        text: "do_not_import",
        custom: null,
        updates: true,
        removes: true,
    },
];

const consolidateArray = [];

for(const data of newData){
    const getObjectFromFilterArray = filterData.find(x => x.value === data.value);
    if(getObjectFromFilterArray){
        consolidateArray.push(getObjectFromFilterArray);
    }else{
        consolidateArray.push(data);
    }
}


console.log(consolidateArray);
```